# How to Execute command from within BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to execute a number of commands from with BASH. My first question is why the following command is not executed, when from CMD Line works fine.

```
# Variables
ArchiverLog="/tmp/JSM04-Archiver-GC.log"

Archiver=$(ps -ef | grep 'java' | grep -i 'archiver-component' |      awk '{print "jstat -gcutil "$2" 200 10 >> "}')
echo $Archiver
echo $ArchiverLog
Archiver="$Archiver $ArchiverLog"
echo Running jstats For Archiver ...............................

command $Archiver
```

What ever I try the '>>' are not being passed as expected and the command does not run..

```
command $Archiver
+ command jstat -gcutil 30467 200 10 '>>' /tmp/JSM04-Archiver-GC.log
+ jstat -gcutil 30467 200 10 '>>' /tmp/JSM04-Archiver-GC.log
invalid argument count
```

How do I pass '>>' successfully ??

Second Question, I would like to run this command for 3 different processes, what's the best way to do this, I want to run them in parrellel at the same time, would it be 3 separate BASH scripts ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're making your life harder than it needs to be. Just don't add the redirection to the string in the awk thingy.

Comment: Tried removing that - still fails.

Comment: Remove >> from awk. Do not make Archiver="$Archive Archivelog". In command part use:- command $Archiver >> $Archivelog

Comment: Perfect !!!! Thanks Shravan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to do this.

```
ArchiverLog="/tmp/JSM04-Archiver-GC.log"

something=$(ps -ef | grep 'java' | grep -i 'archiver-component' | awk '{print $2}')
jstat -gcutil "$something" 200 10 >> "$ArchiverLog"
```

I'm not sure what `$something` is; you can give the variable a more sensible name.

For the second part of your question, you can use `&` at the end of a command to execute the command in the background, then use `wait` at the end to wait for all background jobs to complete.